# C++ OpenSSL RSA_free give Segmentation fault if EVP_PKEY_free is also used

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I'm writing a small program to test an old issue on RSA. I need to access the prime factors of the modulus. So my code is

```
int RSAKeyGen(int keySize) {

      EVP_PKEY *pkey  = EVP_PKEY_new();

      BIGNUM *bn = BN_new();
      BN_set_word(bn, RSA_F4);

      RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
      RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, keySize, bn, NULL);

      EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa);

      const BIGNUM *p;
      const BIGNUM *q;

      RSA_get0_factors(rsa, &p,&q);

      BN_print_fp(stdout, p);
      puts("\n");
      BN_print_fp(stdout, q);

      RSA_free(rsa);
      EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
      BN_free(bn);

      return 0;
}
```

Having both  `EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);` and `RSA_free(rsa);` gives

```
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
```

commenting one of them is working fine, except may be something is not freed. Changed the order but did not worked.

- Does only one of them is enough to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation for `EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA` here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA.html

As stated on that page:

> EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DSA(), EVP_PKEY_assign_DH(), EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(), EVP_PKEY_assign_POLY1305() and EVP_PKEY_assign_SIPHASH() also set the referenced key to key however these use the supplied key internally and so key will be freed when the parent pkey is freed.

So in other words ownership of the key assigned via the `EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA()` call is transferred to the EVP_PKEY. When you free the `EVP_PKEY` it also frees the underlying `RSA` key. So, once you've successfully called `EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA()` you must not call `RSA_free()` on the underlying key or a double-free may result.

Comment: That one line is the definite answer. Thnx.

Comment: Faced the same when tried warp all openssl pointers by std::unique_ptr ((

 `ret = RSA_set0_key(publicKey.get(), n.get(), e.get(),NULL);`